# How to insert an array as a new document after the .aggregation in mongodb?

Tags: javascript, mongodb

I wanner insert a var object as a new document after aggregation operation in MongoDB.
I try this method:

```
    var postUpvote = db.collection.aggregation([
    {$limit:1}
    ]).toArray()

    db.collection.aggregation([
    ...
    ...
    ]).insert(postUpvote[0])
```

But db.collection.aggregation(...).instert() is not a function.
The second aggregation result is just one document.
 And I also try to use $addFields to insert the postUpvote to the document, but I can't take this inserted file out of the document into a new document.

```
{
    "_id" : 1671,
    "CommentUserId" : 1671,
    "CommentUserUpVote" : 2644,
    "PostUserId" : 1671,
    "PostUserVote" : 2644
}
```

The PostUserId and PostUserVote is the var postUpvote.
The result I want is

```
{
    "_id" : 1671,
    "CommentUserId" : 1671,
    "CommentUserUpVote" : 2644,
}
{
    "_id": //Whatever, I don't care
    "PostUserId" : 1671,
    "PostUserVote" : 2644
}
```

Comment: I don't known what you really want to do. But if you want to insert a array as a output of a aggregation stage. You can using project stage for this case.

Comment: emmmm, I want to insert a new document which is the var postUpvote, to the aggregation result. And I also try to use $addFields to insert the postUpvote to the document, but I can't take this inserted file out of the document into a new document.@PhongNguyen

Comment: `aggregation()` would return a cursor, so you won't be able to do `insert()` on them. Why don't you just use `aggregation().toArray()` into a variable, manipulate that variable as you see fit, then `insert()` the processed data manually?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [$out](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/out/) aggregation as a last step in your pipeline. But it replaces the output collection completely if it already exists. If you want to avoid it try [$merge](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/merge/#pipe._S_merge) aggregation. It can incorporate results (insert new documents, merge documents, replace documents, keep existing documents, fail the operation, process documents with a custom update pipeline) into an existing collection.